# Determine the $2023$th derivative of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Determine $f^{2023}(x)$, the derivative of order $2023$.

Note that
$$
f^{1}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2x^{1/2}}, \ \ f^{2}(x) = -\dfrac{1}{2^{2}x^{3/2}} \ \ f^{3}(x) = \dfrac{3}{2^{3}x^{5/2}} \ \ f^{4}(x) = -\dfrac{15}{2^{4}x^{7/2}} \ \ f^{5}(x) = \dfrac{105}{2^{5}x^{9/2}}
$$
Then, So of course in the denominator we have $2^{n}x^{(2n-1)/2}$. However, I am not able to obtain a relation for the numbered and then take $n = 2023$. I just know that we have a $(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: **Hint :** $105=1 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I knew that, but how to get a parameter?

Comment: I believe that, using induction, the coefficient is $(2n+1)!!$ where $!!$ is the double factorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted already, the missing piece you're looking for is the double factorial. And just to make things explicit and convincing, we can prove:

$$
f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n-3)!!}{2^nx^{(2n-1)/2}}
$$

For all natural numbers $n$ using induction, like Kamal mentioned.

When $n = 1$, as you noted:

$f^1(x) = \frac{1}{2x^{1/2}} = \frac{(-1)^{2}(-1)!!}{2x^{1/2}} = \frac{(-1)^{1+1}(2(1)-3)!!}{2^1x^{(2(1)-1)/2}}$

So the result holds when $n = 1$<sup>*</sup>.

Now for the induction hypothesis, suppose the result holds when $n = k, k \in \mathbb{N}$. Now consider $n = k + 1$:

$$
f^{(k+1)}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[f^{(k)}(x)] = \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k-3)!!}{2^kx^{(2k-1)/2}}], \text{ by the induction hypothesis}
$$

Now taking the derivative we get:

$$
\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k-3)!!}{2^k} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{x^{(2k-1)/2}}] =
\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k-3)!!}{2^k} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}[x^{-(2k-1)/2}] = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k-3)!!}{2^k} \cdot \frac{-(2k-1)}{2} \cdot x^{-(2k-1)/2-1} = \frac{(-1)^{k+2}(2k-1)(2k-3)!!}{2^{k+1}} \cdot x^{-(2k+1)/2} = \frac{(-1)^{k+2}(2k-1)!!}{2^{k+1}x^{(2k+1)/2}}
$$

Completing the induction.

So now using our formula,

$$
f^{(2023)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{2023+1}(2(2023)-3)!!}{2^{2023}x^{(2(2023)-1)/2}} = \frac{(4043)!!}{2^{2023}x^{4045/2}}
$$

---

<sup>*Note I'm using the definition of the double factorial that defines (-1)!! = 1: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem @JhonMec

Answer (score 4):

As you have noted, the derivatives follow the pattern:

$$f^n(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}a_n}{2^nx^{n-1/2}}$$

Where the sequence $a = [1, 1, 3, 15, 105, 945, 10395, 135135, \dots]$.  And the part you're struggling with is that you don't know the name or formula for this sequence.

Fortunately, we have a useful tool called [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) that lets you search for number sequences, and it turns out that plugging in the numbers above gives you sequence [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147), the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) for odd integers.

So, you're looking for $a_{2023} = 1 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times \dots \times 4045$.  The exact value of this number is too long to write here, but its approximate value is $3.85586 \times 10^{6418}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Hint…If you don’t like the double factorial notation you might like to consider the following:
$$1\times3\times5\times7\times…\times4045$$
$$=\frac{1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times6\times7\times…\times4046}{2\times4\times6\times…\times4046}$$
$$=\frac{4046!}{2^{2023}\times2023!}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x^{\frac12}$

We will prove by induction that

$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{(2n-3)!!}{2^nx^{\frac{2n-1}2}}\quad$ for all $\,n\in\Bbb N\,\land\,n\geqslant2\,.\;\,\,\color{blue}{(*)}$

For $\;n=2\;,\,(*)\,$ is true , indeed

$\begin{align}f^{(n)}(x)&=f’’(x)=Df’(x)=D\left(\dfrac12x^{\frac12-1}\right)=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac12-1\right)x^{\frac12-2}=\\[3pt]
&=\dfrac{1(1-2)}{2^2x^{2-\frac12}}=(-1)^{2+1}\dfrac{1!!}{2^2x^{\frac{2\cdot2-1}2}}=(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{(2n-3)!!}{2^nx^{\frac{2n-1}2}}\,.\end{align}$

Let $\,h\in\Bbb N\,\land\,h\geqslant3\,.$
Now we suppose that $\,(*)\,$ is true for $\,n=h-1\geqslant2\,$ and we will prove that $\,(*)\,$ is true for $\,n=h\,$ too.

$\begin{align}f^{(h)}(x)&=Df^{(h-1)}(x)=D\left[(-1)^h\dfrac{(2h-5)!!}{2^{h-1}x^{\frac{2h-3}2}}\right]=\\[3pt]
&=(-1)^h\dfrac{(2h-5)!!}{2^{h-1}}D\left(x^{-\frac{2h-3}2}\right)=\\[3pt]
&=(-1)^h\dfrac{(2h-5)!!}{2^{h-1}}\left(-\dfrac{2h-3}2\right)x^{-\frac{2h-3}2-1}=\\[3pt]
&=(-1)^{h+1}\dfrac{(2h-3)!!}{2^h}x^{-\frac{2h-1}2}=\\[3pt]
&=(-1)^{h+1}\dfrac{(2h-3)!!}{2^hx^{\frac{2h-1}2}}\;,\end{align}$

hence , $\,(*)\,$ is also true for $\;n=h\;.$

Therefore, by induction, $\,(*)\,$ is true for all $\,n\in\Bbb N\,\land\,n\geqslant2\,.$

---

**Addendum :**
If we use the definition of the double factorial that defines $\,(-1)!! = 1\,$ ( [see here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) ) , then $\,(*)\,$ is true for $\,n=1\,$ too.

Comment: Thank you very much.